# location of .properties file in Scala Akka project

Tags: scala, akka

I have an akka project, in which I am building a `Properties` object using the code:

```
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException
   import java.util.Properties
   import scala.io.Source

    val configPath = "hikari.properties"

    val url = getClass.getResource(hikariConfigPath)

    val properties: Properties = new Properties()

    if (url != null) {

      val source = Source.fromURL(url)

      properties.load(source.bufferedReader())

    } else {

      println("properties file cannot be loaded at path " + configPath)

      throw new FileNotFoundException("Properties file cannot be loaded”)

    }
```

And this is giving me “properties file cannot be loaded at path hikari.properties”

with the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Properties file cannot be loaded
    at model.daos.JavaConnectionFactoryBuilder$.buildDataSource(JavaConnectionFactory.scala:25)
```

I have put the `hikari.properties` file in the `src/main/resources` directory as advised by https://zetcode.com/articles/hikaricp/

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a non existent file `hikari.` instead of `hikari.properties`.

It should be:

```scala
 val hikariConfigPath = "hikari.propertiez"
```

Comment: When I write it as you have typed, I get the error: "properties file cannot be loaded at path hikari.propertiesproperties file cannot be loaded at path hikari.properties"

Comment: It seems like it attaches properties to the name of the file.

Comment: How are you running your code? Is the properties file properly packaged with the app?

Comment: I’m using `sbt -Dakka.cluster.roles.0=read-model "runMain scaffold.Main 2551”` to run it in development mode.

Comment: the mystery of the properties attachment to the file name is solved. It just doesn’t put any space between the first and second printing of the message. If I write `println` it would get solved. so not related to the file name. but even when writing the file name as “hikari.properties” I get the same problem.